# if ( Selection < 0) and (Selection > 3) condition behaves differently for input =4. Why?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
def PrintBlue():
    print (" You chose Blue!\r\n")

def PrintRed():
    print (" You chose Red!\r\n")

def PrintOrange():
    print (" You chose Orange!\r\n")

def PrintYellow():
    print (" You chose Yellow!\r\n")

#Let's create a dictionary with unique key

ColorSelect = {
    0:PrintBlue,
    1:PrintRed,
    2:PrintOrange,
    3:PrintYellow
    }

Selection = 0

while (Selection != 4):
    print ("0.Blue")
    print ("1.Red")
    print ("2.Orange")
    print ("3.Yellow")
    try:
        Selection = int(input("Select a color option: "))
        x=0
        if ( Selection < 0) and (Selection > 3):
            raise KeyError(" Enter a number >=0 and <4)")
        else:
            ColorSelect[Selection]() # Run the function inside dictionary as well
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Above is my python code. I am using 2.7 version. but after running I got different result for input =4. While I am expecting same result for Selection<0 or >3.Here is result look like:

0.Blue
1.Red
2.Orange
3.Yellow
Select a color option: 5
0.Blue
1.Red
2.Orange
3.Yellow
Select a color option: 4

> > > 

Notice after I enter input =4 , python exits from run time.When I enter 0,1,2,3,5,6,7, every time it ask again to enter value again, but when I enter 4 it exits.

Comment: As you have mentioned `while(selection !=4)` it exits the loop.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I just embarrassed to see while (Selection != 4): in my code.

Comment: the condition `if (Selection < 0) and (Selection > 3)` is always false. Selection cannot be both less than 0 AND greater than 3. The appropriate operator is `or`, not `and`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( Selection < 0) and (Selection > 3):
```

means "if Selection is both less than zero and greater than three", which can't happen. I suspect you mean

```
if ( Selection < 0) or (Selection > 3):
```

which will raise an error for an input outside of the valid range.

The program is exiting when you enter 4 because of

```
while (Selection != 4):
```

If that's not the desired behavior, you need to change that line. For example, if you want the loop to run forever, it could be just

```
while True:
```

Comment: Thanks for nicely figuring it out and also giving me some insight!

Answer (score 1):

You have "while (Selection != 4)" on line 24 -- when the selection is equal to 4 the while loop (and the program) exits.